# MEDICAL STATISTICS QUESTION: When log odds (B) is 0.034 and OR (Exp B) is 1.034 for death, what is the OR for a 10 year change in age?

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

In regression analysis, one year increase in age is associated with Exp(0.034) / 1.034 increase in odds of death. The question is when there is a 10 year age difference what is the odds ratio and confidence intervals.

Am i correct in multiplying 0.034 by 10 to give a log odds of 0.34 and the exponential of this giving an odds ratio of 1.4?

Then would confidence intervals be:

Exp (b  1.96 SE(B))
Exp (0.34  1.96 x 0.012)
Exp (0.34  0.0235)
Exp (0.36) and Exp (0.32) = 1.34 to 1.43 ?

Comment: Also, the intercept is -5.772 for multiple logistic regression of age/type of hospital admission/level of consciousness - do i need to include the intercept in this calculation or is it irrelevant for change in age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the odds ratio for a 10 year difference in age is correct. You do not need the intercept as you are only interested in the difference in age holding everything else constant. I was not clear about your confidence interval calculation as you did not give us the standard error of the coefficient but if you have followed the same principle (multiply the se by 10 too) it should be correct.

Comment: Why would you multiply the standard error by 10? Wouldn't it just be new estimate on the log scale +/ 1.96 SEs?

Comment: @Tdisher suppose it was 100000 rather than 10. Would you expect the width of the confidence interval to be the same?

Comment: Based on replicating calculations here http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2011/ST07.Lewis.pdf by hand I see that you are right. Multiplying the se by 10 gives the same results the the actual SAS output. Thanks for the lesson! @mdewey

Comment: Thankyou! I actually hadn't multiplied SE by 10. The original SE of the coefficient was 0.012, so now the intervals I have are 1.1-1.79. Does that sound correct?